# Spectral Decomposition of Equicorrelation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let R = $(1-\rho)I_p + \rho1_p1_p^{'}$ , aka the equicorrelation matrix.

How can I generate the spectral decomposition of R using the fact that the spectral decomposition of $I_p$ is:

$I_p = \sum_{i=1}^{p} e_ie_i^{'}$ , and we can choose the first eigenvector $e_1 = (1/\sqrt(p))1_p$

I was able to derive the actual eigenvalues of R using det(A-$\lambda I) = 0$ but how can I leverage the above statements?

Comment: The spectral decomposition of $I_p$ is not a useful starting point. However, the spectral decomposition of $\rho 11'$ is a useful starting point.